# Highlight multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to select multiple text boxes at once and initiate the copy to clipboard command but only the 3rd text field always gets highlighted or selected.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="copyText" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input type="text" class="copyText" laceholder="Phone"><br>
<input type="text" class="copyText" placeholder="E-Mail"><br>
<button>Copy</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var copyText =  $(':input[type="text"]';
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('Text Copied');
});
```

Comment: Here is my html

<input type='text' class='copyText' placeholder="Name"><br>
            <input type='text' class='copyText' placeholder="Phone"><br>
            <input type='text' class='copyText' placeholder="E-Mail"><br>
            <button>Copy</button>

Comment: You should try iterating over the elements you want to copy and prepare the whole content to store in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is more like a hack, but works, because we have to create an element and hide it with `position:absolute;left:-1000px`. The idea is to iterate over inputs and save the values into an array, then we have to store those values into a new input that is not visible. And finally we select the value of that input.

```js
   $('button').on('click', function() {

  var values = $('.copyText').map(function(i, e) {
return $(e).val();
  }).get();

  var phantom = document.createElement("textarea");
  phantom.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;left:-1000px");

  phantom.innerHTML =  values.join("\n");

  document.body.appendChild(phantom);

  phantom.select();

  document.execCommand('copy');
  alert('Text Copied');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="copyText" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input type="text" class="copyText" laceholder="Phone"><br>
<input type="text" class="copyText" placeholder="E-Mail"><br>
<button>Copy</button>
```

Comment: This is awesome and it indeed works, my only problem now is the line breaks. It seems there is a break during the copy process.

John Smith,123456,Newyork

Comment: @Felgie where is the break? because I'm using `values.toString()` and that join the array like `value1,value2,value3`. But we could use another way, like  `values.join(" ")` or something .

Comment: when you copy the values entered, they all go single line
John Smith,123456,John.Smith@gmail.com
i can't figure out where to put \n or something

Comment: Ah ok, so you want a line break between elements. values.join("\n") should work.

Comment: for some reason the output still showing as single line, i've tried \r\n and still the same thing 
John Smith123456j.s@email.com

Comment: @Felgie Ok now it works. I've updated the code again. the problem was that `<input>` element doesn't accept line breaks, but `<textarea>` does. The code also works in mobiles, try to copy and paste in google keep.

Comment: @Emmet this is absolutely working now! I will just work with the labels instead of placeholder and copy those labels along with the inputs. Thank you for all your help!!!!

Comment: @Felgie your welcome! accept the answer if you find it useful

Comment: @Felgie to copy the placeholders too, you could something like this https://jsfiddle.net/80fhrbwq/

Comment: what an added bonus! iloveyou forever now!

Answer (score 0):

Use `each()` function of jQuery

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $(':input[type="text"]').each(function( index ){
      $(this).select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      alert('Text Copied');
    });
});
```

Doc jQuery : https://api.jquery.com/each/